# WebGL inside of ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, browser, webgl

I have a question relating to WebGL (with javascript) being implemented inside of ASP.NET. I currently am working on a project in which I want to be able to use WebGL to load a up a model but have the features inside of ASP.Net to do other tasks.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: WebGL is clientside, ASP is serverside. What do you want to know?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest use of [THREE.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js) library for it. It's pretty solid and has good vibrant community , but yet a lot of stuff yet to be done, imo.

The good strating point you can find here: [Learning Three.js](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/12/20/boilerplate-for-three-js/)

What about `ASP.NET` setup, you can use whatever setup you want or feel comfortable with: WebForms or MVC. At the end what you need is

- HTML data rendering  (WebForms. MVC, node.js...)
- javascript to work with `WebGL` (`three.js`)
- *json* requests to *push* and *pull* data (usually in chunks, as `3D` models tend to be big and easily overflow available *json* data limit, so you need to fragment it in small pieces)